# grunt task to modify yeoman angular index.html

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

`yo angular` sets up a basic scaffold for writing angular apps. So in `index.html` we have code as follows:

```
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I am looking for a task that would remove those lines and inject the correct location of the files. For e.g.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
```

Or is there some alternate way to deal with this...like for e.g. have the watch task create different versions of `index.html`, say `index.html.fooTarget`; it gets updated with the correct paths for that target; and then when it comes to the grunt task have the latter file copied appropriately.

What can be done to deal with this?

Comment: Bower installs components into bower_components directory, what's wrong with that?

Comment: I need the distribution-version of those bower files copied to my target folder. So say, it a css file...it should get copied to a `css` folder, and index.html should reflect likewise...its a common thing you face in phone gap/cordova development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should let the paths be as they are since CSS files are bower dependencies, too. Copy the dependencies to a directory with the same relative path?

But if you will, I think this will help you modify your grunt tasks.

I assume you have (at least) the following in your `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-text-replace": "0.3.11"
  }
}
```

Then the minimal copy & replace tasks could look like the following in your `Gruntfile.js` (you can combine copy and replace by using [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) alone, if you will).

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');

    grunt.initConfig({
        src: 'src',
        dest: 'dest',
        copy: {
            dev: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= src %>',
                src: '{,*/}*.html',
                dest: '<%= dest %>/'                
            }
        },
        replace: {
            dev: {
                src: ['<%= dest %>/{,*/}*.html'],
                overwrite: true,
                replacements: [{
                    from: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css',
                    to: 'css'
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('prepare', function(val) {
        var target = val || 'dev';
        grunt.task.run([
            'copy:' + target,
            'replace:' + target
        ]);
    });
};
```

Now when you run `prepare` task with desired `target` it will copy all HTML files from `src` to `dest` directory and have desired CSS paths replaced, leaving original files intact.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" /> 

--> will be replaced as -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Comment: Had to do this for all the files included. :( There must be a better way though. Now when I add a new depedency (via bower) I have to make changes to my copy and replace tasks respectively. Should be able to read index.html walk through all script and css file references and perform a copy and replace task...

Comment: Still, just copy dev bower_components to dist bower_components using same relative path and then you don't have to worry about copy/replace task at all?

Comment: how would I know pre-hand how many files, and, what files to copy? For e.g. for bootstrap jquery is a depedency...I can't figure this out from the bower.json file alone.

Comment: copy bower_components/**/*

Comment: @MikkoViitala, I implemented grunt tasks successfully but my index.html is getting overwritten, can you suggest me a grunt task which will create a copy of index.html to index-dev.html and successfully run the grunt task.?